# Fixing warning C28160: Error annotation caused by use of VirtualFreeEx

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, c++17

I have a function which is giving multiple warnings of type `C28160: Error annotation`, the function is as below:

```
BOOL MemoryApi::VirtualMemFree(HANDLE hProcess, LPVOID lpAddress, SIZE_T dwSize, DWORD dwFreeType) const
{
    return ::VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpAddress, dwSize, dwFreeType);
}
```

How do I fix this warning?

I read the documentation of this warning [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6333?view=msvc-170)  and tried the suggested solution as below, but the warning is not going away.

```
BOOL MemoryApi::VirtualMemFree(HANDLE hProcess, LPVOID lpAddress, SIZE_T dwSize, DWORD dwFreeType) const
{
    if (dwFreeType == MEM_RELEASE) 
        return ::VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
    
    return ::VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpAddress, 0, dwFreeType);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mre] as well as a copy-paste (as text!) of the build log.

Comment: These errors are caused by annotations in memoryapi.h, they check statically how you're using the API at compile time: https://i.imgur.com/BQcPddb.png you should fix them. By experience, they are sometimes wrong and you can ignore them, but it's always worth to look a it and fix it.

Comment: Note that `dwFreeType` can have multiple flags, so use `&` instead of `==` when checking for specific flags. Does this work for you? `if (dwFreeType & MEM_RELEASE) return ::VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpAddress, 0, dwFreeType); else return ::VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpAddress, dwSize, dwFreeType & ~MEM_RELEASE);` Which can be simplified: `if (dwFreeType & MEM_RELEASE) dwSize = 0; return ::VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpAddress, dwSize, dwFreeType);`